# Map in Highcharts not display the India map?

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

We are trying to add a map on Angular to show some random data on an indian map using Highcharts but it does not show the map and there is also no error in my console so it is hard to find the error. We did not find any solution for Angular.

my app.ts file code is given below

```
import { Component,OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Chart } from 'angular-highcharts';
import * as Highcharts from "highcharts";
import * as HighchartsMore from "highcharts/highcharts-more";
import * as HighchartsExporting from "highcharts/modules/exporting";

declare var $;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent  implements OnInit {
  title = "app";
  options: any = {
    colors: ['#f45b5b', '#8085e9', '#8d4654', '#7798BF', '#aaeeee',
    '#ff0066', '#eeaaee', '#55BF3B', '#DF5353', '#7798BF', '#aaeeee'],
    chart: {
      backgroundColor: null,
      style: {
        fontFamily: 'Signika, serif'
      }
    },
    title: {
      style: {
        color: 'black',
        fontSize: '16px',
        fontWeight: 'bold'
      }
    },
    subtitle: {
      style: {
        color: 'black'
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
      borderWidth: 0
    },
    labels: {
      style: {
        color: '#6e6e70'
      }
    },
    legend: {
      backgroundColor: '#E0E0E8',
      itemStyle: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: '13px'
      }
    },
    xAxis: {
      labels: {
        style: {
          color: '#6e6e70'
        }
      }
    },
    yAxis: {
      labels: {
        style: {
          color: '#6e6e70'
        }
      }
    },
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        shadow: true
      },
      candlestick: {
        lineColor: '#404048'
      },
      map: {
        shadow: false
      }
    },
    // Highstock specific
    navigator: {
      xAxis: {
        gridLineColor: '#D0D0D8'
      }
    },
    rangeSelector: {
      buttonTheme: {
        fill: 'white',
        stroke: '#C0C0C8',
        'stroke-width': 1,
        states: {
          select: {
            fill: '#D0D0D8'
          }
        }
      }
    },
    scrollbar: {
      trackBorderColor: '#C0C0C8'
    }
  };
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(){

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#example').DataTable();
    } );


    Highcharts.chart('container', this.options);

    Highcharts.createElement('link', {
      href: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Signika:400,700',
      rel: 'stylesheet',
      type: 'text/css'
    }, null, document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]);
    // Add the background image to the container
    Highcharts.addEvent(Highcharts.Chart, 'afterGetContainer', function () {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-invalid-this
      this.container.style.background =
      'url(https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/sand.png)';
    });
  }




}
```

my html file code is given below

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Where's the "this.container" variable? Also, there seems to be an Angular version for Highcharts: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular#hello-world-demo

Comment: it is id  in html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prepared a demo which shows how to implement an India map in Angular environment.

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-highcharts-stock-sjcf9h?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: which version of highchart  you are using ?

Comment: it is work but map not show the hover color or state name

Comment: it is show the following error 
localhost/:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:4200/css/owl.theme.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Comment: I change the GeoJSON of india map

Comment: I used GeoJSON  of india -all-disputed

Comment: @AyushSahu do you have still some problems with map implementing? Here is a map collection which available maps and demos with basic configuration: https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/ You should be able to reproduce it to your needs base on the Angular demo which I prepared.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `@ViewChild` to connect Highcharts to the template object.

Add this in your component.ts:

```
  @ViewChild('container', { static: false }) container: ElementRef;
```

In your template add the `#container` tag:

```
<div id="container" #container></div>
```

Using the provided [Highcharts Angular version](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular#hello-world-demo) would be easier though.

Comment: it is show error 
 import * as worldMap from "@highcharts/map-collection/custom/world.geo";

Comment: Did you try importing the Angular specific version?

Comment: i am using angular 6

Comment: "highcharts": "^7.0.3",
    "highcharts-angular": "^2.4.0",

Comment: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular#getting-started prerequisites are Angular 6 or higher